# Форма bootstrap перекрывает интер. карту яндекс

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

При этом,если в медизапросе убрать высоту (на скрине справа - elements), то не перекрывает

[image: ...]

Comment: у вас скорее всего неправильная используется сетка bootstrap - одновременно используется и row и col-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для класса `.map-height` добавить `overflow: hidden` и проблема должна исчезнуть